# I'm getting error while downloading virtual device in genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

**Error:** "Failed to deploy virtual device"

> 'Unable to create virtual device:
>   HTTP error response:Unknown error.'

***I'm using ubuntu.***

Comment: Is there any more information you could provide that might be useful?

Comment: its solved... i have just cleared caches from settings in genymotion ... thank you :)